# Which keyboard layout is this with an Alt Gr and a Ç?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Somebody know what kind of layout this keyboard use? I tried at least 50 types and none works.

Its a Asus EEE Pc Seashell Series. On the left have a sticker with italian things....

[image]

Comment: It is a British qwerty. The big clue is the £ sign on the number 3. What is it that isn't working?

Comment: the @ button (with the Ç), the FN button......i tried the Portuguese of Portugal, but not work....

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that. Can you [edit] the question with the make and model of the laptop? I take it that there aren't any drivers on the manufacturer's website?

Comment: Edited. I searched in the asus website, but i found nothing.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/KB_Portuguese.svg/900px-KB_Portuguese.svg.png looks like a match

Comment: It looks like the standard italian keyboard.

Comment: Yes, it is italian layout, almost all the buttons worked, but the DEL still without work....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Italian layout

[image]

And you can see it at [AliExpress](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-Laptop-keyboard-for-ASUS-EeePC-SeaShell-1015-1011PX-1015P-1015PE-1015PN-1015PED-white-Italian-IT/1558644864.html?spm=2114.40010308.4.55.uhgWI5)

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's italian, but the DEL button on the top right isn't work. Before i reinstall the Windows, the DEL work fine.....

Comment: @Diego... You don't state that in your original question though?!!? Did you change the layout in Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards

Comment: Yes, i edited the question yesterday. So, i tried to put the Italian on Region and Language -> Keyboards but some keys still not working....Before the new instalation, all keys work nice, and now, that mess...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a italian layout.
you can change it in Windows 10 by:
opening language, then preferred languages, and click in English (united states), then Options, and under Keyboards, select Add keyboard, then italian QWERTY.
so, you can keep the English language, but with italian, or another keyboard layout.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Unfortunately this time your answer is not really helpful, as the same already has been provided and accepted, and the question is only about identifying the layout, not how to change it in Windows. Please check [the Tour] to learn how things work and how Q&A sites like these differ from internet message boards and forums. Please also go through the Asking and Answering in the [Help section](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how to write good answers and questions. I'm sure your input will be valuable in the future :-)